# Rscript 'NaN' error for every answer in table

Tags: nan, rscript

Im a student and new to using Rscript, Im trying to calculate total score and the mean afterwards, however when the colums come in in the console, it just displays 'Nan' in every slot.
I have put this below, but it doesnt show me how to fix this error, any help would mean the world.

thank you!

1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
8   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
9   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

This is what it keeps displaying, I have tried re-typing the total_score code, but that seems fine and Im not sure how to fix the issue, just before this i ran the cronbach with no issues, and everyone here seems super smart, thank you!

Its clear to tell im no coder and if it wasnt6 neccessary for my research report i wouldnt understand a thing, so any advice i would really apprecaite!

Comment: NaN means not a number. That means you are trying to convert the character to number but that is not a number.

Comment: hi, but all my data is numerical? it's all 1-5? but thank you anyway! i shall try and resolve it :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.